# Sequences Convergent Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have been asked to show that if $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence, which is bounded below by $M \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \geq M.$

Now I feel as though this is extremely obvious, as the question itself states that $(a_n) \geq M$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, so as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then clearly it is still greater than $M$?

Is it sufficient to write this or is there another way to show it?

Comment: Suppose the limit was $k<M$. Then take $\delta>0$ such that $k+\delta<M$. Now we cannot have $|a_n-k|<\delta$.

Comment: Your statment "then clearly it is still greater than M" doesn't really make sense. Try to prove it if it's so bleepin' obvious! Hint: Suppose the limit equals L < M. Take epsilon = (M-L)/2

Comment: I would look for a theorem in your textbook (that you've already covered) which is close to the result, cite that theorem, and use it to prove the result.  If that approach fails, I'd use the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$, taken again from the textbook, directly in a proof.  In a closed book exam, as a matter of examsmanship, you are faced with a somewhat trickier issue when asked to prove something like this that's obvious.  Given sufficient time on the exam, I'd feel tempted to write a proof with an epsilon in it just to avoid being marked down for not showing enough work.

Comment: @zhw. It might really be seemingly obvious.  But as you're suggesting, the "obvious" needs proof.

Comment: Use the definition of a limit, and suppose by contradiction that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n<M$. Conclude there needs to be some $a_i$ with $a_i<M$.